# Count the number of records based on a variable criteria Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as follow:

```
dashboard = pd.DataFrame({
 'id':[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4],
 'level': [1,2,2.1,2.2,3,3.1,4,1.1,2,3,4],
 'cost': [10,6,4,8,9,6,11,23,3,2,12],
 'category': ['Original', 'Time', 'Money','Original','Original','Time','Original','Original','Time','Original','Original']
})
```

I need to get the following table where if for example the level is 3, the code will sum all the previous levels only (2.2, 2.1 - excluding 2):

```
pd.DataFrame({
 'id': [1,2,3,4],
 'level': [3,4,2,4],
 'cost': [12,6,23,0],
 'category': ['Time & Money','Time','Time','']
})
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way

```
df2 = dashboard.groupby('id')['level'].last().astype(int).reset_index()
df2['cost'] = dashboard.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x[x['level']>=(x['level'].tail(1)-0.9).sum()]['cost'].sum()-x['cost'].tail(1)).reset_index(drop=True)
df2['category'] = dashboard.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x[x['level']>=(x['level'].tail(1)-0.9).sum()].groupby('id')['category'].agg(' & '.join)).reset_index(drop=True).replace('Original','', regex=True).str.strip((' & '))
df2
```

**Output** (the input & the output you have provided do not math for column 'category')

```
id  level   cost    category
0   1   3   12      Money
1   2   4   6       Time
2   3   2   23      Time
3   4   4   0
```